# K3b - BluRay disc burning fails at 5 MB

Tags: k3b

I am trying to burn bluray disc using K3b. But it fails after writing 5 MB. Attaching the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: oops... click on "enter image description here" to check the screenshot.

Comment: The message says to try burning at a slower speed, can you try burning at the slowest (probably 1x) speed? (I hope you're trying with RW discs... all the bluray discs don't seem very "affordable")

Comment: I have already tried with speed ranging from 1x to 6x. But it fails everytime. Already wasted 7 - 8 disc. Not sure what's the reason.

Comment: I'd get a re-writeable (RW) disk before trying again, sounds like something just isn't right. Sometimes a brand or batch of disks just don't like a writer, not sure it isn't a linux/ubuntu problem either... There might be a different writing "mode" to try too (under Writing tab, writing mode) but I'm not sure how bluray uses modes... used to have things like disk-at-once or track-at-once...

Comment: K3b was burning these discs without any problem. All of a sudden this problem started.

Comment: The suspicion about the buffer underrun does not apply to BD-R media.
They can stand that. Speed should be no problem either (except noise).
The "RW" discs of the BD world are named BD-RE. Well affordable meanwhile.
Can it be that the "Not necessarily serious" i/o errors happen when
reading the input files ? What do you see when you click the
"Show Debugging Output" button at the lower right of the window ?

Comment: /usr/bin/cdrecord: The current problem looks like a buffer underrun.
/usr/bin/cdrecord: It looks like 'driveropts=burnfree' does not work for this drive.
/usr/bin/cdrecord: Please report.
/usr/bin/cdrecord: Make sure that you are root, enable DMA and check your HW/OS set up.

Comment: These messages make few sense with BD-R media. No others to see ?
(I'd propose to use growisofs instead of cdrecord if i knew how
to talk K3b into doing this. Is growisofs installed ?)
But regardless of the clueless messages, i suspect that the problem
is not so much in burn program or burner drive but rather with the
input.

Comment: Already tried with growisofs. Burning do fail but at 0% unlike cdrecord which is at 5 MB. But point is cdrecord was working earlier. Don't know what happened all of a sudden. I have tried different types of different files but still burning fails after writing 5 MB of data.

Comment: We need tangible error messages. Not those shown up to now.
Can you run growisofs directly without K3B ?

Comment: I tried burning the disc in Windows 10 using BurnAware software. Burning failed at 6MB. Error message indicated that media might not be compatible. So, got Sony BluRays. Tried burning with K3b and it was successful. Only thing that I don't understand that previous discs which used with K3b used to work, how it became incompatible all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0):

I met this behaviour of K3b: I prepared 15GB data folder to be written to a BD-R. I ordered K3b to keep the iso, if it were needed for some later copy. First I let the K3b self decide the writing speed - the mission failed. Next I forced the speed 4x, with this speed the disk was burned. But when I asked next day to burn the same disk but from saved ISO image the K3b did not recognised the media (Verbatim 26BG 4x). I tried to burn the ISO with CLI:

```
# wodim -v dev=/dev/sr0 -dao image.iso
```

but got the error message that medium is unknown and cannot find hidden track ... Hence the medium and the right speed could be the reason.
I googled and modified this:

```
# growisofs -dvd-compat -speed=4 -Z /dev/dvd=image.iso
```

what burned the ISO image successfully.
I hope this could be helpful for somebody.

N.B.: I tryed the Brasero for this purpose also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Documentation says

> **Brasero and K3B can't burn Blu-ray out of the box.** In order to do so you have to install the cdrecord package from this PPA [https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/cdrtools](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebrandonsnider/+archive/cdrtools) and in doing so you will be uninstalling wodim which is used by default and does not support BD-R media. See how to add a PPA.
>
> Once you added the PPA, simply install cdrecord package as any other package.
>
> Then you have to install K3b if you did not have it already installed and enable "Show advanced GUI elements" in the advanced settings.

Source - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning

Comment: The screenshot shows that an original cdrecord of 2016 was used, not wodim. Letting K3B use cdrecord for DVD or BD is rather unusual. growisofs is normal. The statement about Brasero and K3B and Blu-ray is outdated.